# beforefeatureadded event equivalent for OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

For openlayers 2, you had an event called beforefeatureadded that you could do validation before actually adding a new feature. What is the equivalent of beforefeatureadded event for OpenLayers 3?

OpenLayers 2 example:

```
layer.events.register("beforefeatureadded", layer, validationFunction);
```

Comment: There's no equivalent but maybe you show some more context of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Looking at @Robert Smith's attempt to add this to OpenLayers (https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4818), I finally understand the question. It's not really about a beforefeatureadded event. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to the OpenLayers 2 `beforefeatureadded` event is the use of a staging collection for drawn features:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector();
var features = new ol.Collection();
features.on('add', function(evt) {
  var feature = evt.element;
  if (conditionMet(feature)) {
    source.addFeature(evt.element);
  }
  // clear the staging collection
  features.pop();
});
```

What's also possible is the use of a Draw condition, and this is what @robert-smith actually wants here:

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  condition: function(evt) {
    return ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys(evt) && conditionMet(evt);
  }
});
```